# Hadoop Big Data - Compute Intensive Example explanation

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I have just started learning Hadoop. In a book there is an example which I don't fully understand.

Example

```
Consider processing 200 GB of data with 50 nodes, in which each node processes 4 GB 
of data located on a local disk. Each node takes 80 seconds to read the data (at the 
rate of 50 MB per second). No matter how fast we compute, we cannot finish in under 80 
seconds. Assume that the result of the process is a total dataset of size 200 MB, and 
each node generates 4 MB of this result. which is transferred over a 1 Gbps (1 MB per 
packet) network to a single node for display. It will take about 3 milliseconds (each 
1 MB requires 250 microseconds to transfer over the network, and the network latency 
per packet is assumed to be 500 microseconds (based on the previously referenced talk 
by Dr. Jeff Dean) to transfer the data to the destination node. Ignoring computational 
costs, the total processing time cannot be under 40.003 seconds.
```

In the above example, I couldn't figure out how the transfer time 3 milliseconds and total processing time 40.003 seconds results are derived.

Comment: It clearly states that: `It will take about 3 milliseconds (each 
1 MB requires 250 microseconds to transfer over the network, and the network latency 
per packet is assumed to be 500 microseconds` and the latter should probably be 80.003.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Could you elaborate? 1 MB takes 750 microseconds (250 + 500) hence 4MB 2800 microseconds i.e. 2.8 milliseconds?